# How do I do Authentication in Angular when there are Promises all over the place?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, authentication, promise

I am building a basic application in Angular demonstrating authentication and I'm getting my ass kicked by Promises.

I've read at least 20 articles, and I think I get how promises work -- they return when they feel like it and you have to keep that in mind -- but I can't seem to "escape" from them. I need a `boolean` value in the end, and I can't seem to get that.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  isAuthenticated: boolean = false;

  public isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    console.log('isLoggedIn before: ' + this.isAuthenticated);
    this.checkUser();
    console.log('isLoggedIn after: ' + this.isAuthenticated);
    return this.isAuthenticated;
  }

  public async checkUser(): Promise<void> {
    // myAuthenticationObject only has userInfo if the user is logged in
    await myAuthentication0bject.userInfo().then((user) => {
      this.isAuthenticated = user !== undefined;
    });
  }
}
```

This doesn't work because the `checkUser` call returns before `isAuthenticated` is set despite the fact that `checkUser` has `async` defined. (`userInfo` is a Promise)

If I make `isLoggedIn` an `async` function so I can await `checkUser`, then I'm right back where I started -- with a Promise that I can't get the `boolean` out of.

I'm clearly missing something here (or maybe it's just not doable -- happy to accept that fact!) and could use some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait the promise:

```
public async isLoggedIn(): Promise<boolean> {
    console.log('isLoggedIn before: ' + this.isAuthenticated);
    await this.checkUser();
    console.log('isLoggedIn after: ' + this.isAuthenticated);
    return this.isAuthenticated;
  }

  public async checkUser(): Promise<void> {
    // myAuthenticationObject only has userInfo if the user is logged in
    let user = await myAuthentication0bject.userInfo();
    this.isAuthenticated = user !== undefined;
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but if I set `isLoggedIn` to be `async`, then it must return a `Promise<boolean>` not a simple `boolean`

Comment: @NickHodges, Yes sorry. It's a problema for you? You can call it with await (eg: `await authService.IsLoggedIn()`)

Answer (score 0):

Nick here to answer you own question.

Alas -- Promise Resolution is one of the hardest things to learn in front end programming, especially if you come from native Windows programming.

So, it goes like this:  Stop trying to be imperative.  Just return a Promise, and then let the UI bind to that Promise, trusting that it will be resolved in due course.

So, here's what you need to do:

First, just embrace Promises and return one from your `isLoggedIn()` call:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { PassageUser } from '@passageidentity/passage-elements/passage-user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService  {
  isAuthenticated: boolean = false;
  myUser: PassageUser = new PassageUser();
  constructor() {

}

  public async isLoggedIn(): Promise<boolean> {
    return await myAuthenticationObject.then(userInfo => {
       this.isAuthenticated = userInfo !== undefined;
       return this.isAuthenticated;

  })
}

}
```

`isAuthenticated` will be set in due course, and your UI will know that and properly deal with it.  Then, in your Component, do this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AuthService } from '../service/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-restricted',
  templateUrl: './restricted.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./restricted.component.css'],
})
export class RestrictedComponent implements OnInit {
  public isAuthenticated: boolean = false;
  public token: string | null = '';

  constructor(protected authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.isLoggedIn().then((result) => {
      this.isAuthenticated = result;
      this.token = localStorage.getItem('psg_auth_token');} );
  }
}
```

Then the property fields will be set in due course, and your UI will properly handle all of that.

Next, in your HTML:

```
<div class="dashboard" *ngIf="isAuthenticated">
  <div class="title">
    Hey there!
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    You have successfully signed in!
    <br /><br />
    <p><b>Token</b> {{ token }}</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="dashboard" *ngIf="!isAuthenticated">
  <div class="title">
    Unauthorized
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    Sorry -- you aren't allowed to see this stuff unless you are logged in.
    <br /><br />
    <a href="/login" className={styles.link}>Login to continue.</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that you use the `isAuthenticated` variable, and not a direct call to the AuthService.

The whole idea here is that you sort of have to trust Angular to deal with the Promises, and not think about trying to be imperative.  If you are fighting with Promises, stop.  Instead, embrace them, and let the framework deal with them.

Your imperative programming days are over. Embrace the asynchronous world!